# Powsershell script to run 2 exe - with Administrator privilege and Current logged user

Tags: powershell, deployment, process

I want to write a Powershell script for :

- 1 run an exe in Administrator privilege to install software
- 2 run another exe with current logged user rights without credential prompt.

Here is my Powershell script :

```
# This Powershell script is used to deploy an application on user desktop who don't have Administrative rights
# This script is run as Administrator


# Get current user logged
$user = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem | % Username
write-host "User: " $user


#Start the process with the Administrative privilege
(Start-Process -FilePath "setup.exe").WaitForExit()

#Start the process agent as current user logged
Start-Process -FilePath "agent.exe" -Credential $User
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? Have any work to show? What part exactly are you stuck at? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you need help learning how to code or troubleshoot something then this is the place for you. If you need code from scratch then you should hire a developer.

Comment: I updated my request with my script

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? If you want to use the credential parameter you need to provide credentials. A username is not enough

Comment: We need to execute the agent.exe process with the current logged user rights and non as administrator rights and all that silently - without prompt.

Comment: I thnik in this case you should create a sheduled task with powershell which will run with the current logged in user

Comment: That's what I saw with this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902301/run-powershell-command-as-currently-logged-in-user

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by doing this:

```
    #Start the setup with the Administrative privilege
    Write-Host "Start setup"
    Start-Process -FilePath $LocalSetupFilePath -ArgumentList "/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART -Encryption=Auto" -NoNewWindow -Wait
    Write-Host "Installation completed"

    #Create scheduled task for start agent
    $agentTaskName = "RunAgent"
    $taskPath = "\"
    $OSArch = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture

    Write-Host "OSArchitecture= $OSArch"
    If ($OSArch -like '64*') {
        $ProgFilePath=$env:ProgramW6432
    } else
    { 
        $ProgFilePath=$env:ProgramFiles
    }
    $agentFilePath = [IO.Path]::Combine($ProgFilePath, "agent.exe")
    Write-Host "Run $agentFilePath"

    $time = (Get-Date).AddHours(1).ToShortTimestring();

    # Create & Run scheduled task to start agent
    schtasks /create /s $ComputerName /tn $agentTaskName /sc once /tr "cmd /c start '' '$agentFilePath'" /st $time /ru $UserName
    schtasks /run /tn $agentTaskName

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    Write-Host "Stop & delete $agentTaskName"
    #Stop scheduled task
    schtasks /end /tn $agentTaskName
    #Remove scheduled task
    schtasks /delete /tn $agentTaskName /f

    Write-Host "Success"
```